# How to distribute spend amount based on partition - sql?

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following table:

| site | subtier | part_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| site A | AA | 123 |
| site A | AB | 1234 |
| site A | AB | 12345 |
| site B | AA | 123 |
| site B | AB | 1234 |
| site B | AB | 12345 |
| site C | AA | 123 |
| site C | AB | 1234 |
| site C | AB | 12345 |

Based on the above:

- There are 3 distinct sites, 2 distinct subtiers and 3 distinct parts
- I have a spend total amount of 964520.15625

This amount needs to be distributed as follows:

| site | subtier | part_number | past spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site A | AA | 123 | 160753.359 |
| site A | AB | 1234 | 80376.6797 |
| site A | AB | 12345 | 80376.6797 |
| site B | AA | 123 | 160753.359 |
| site B | AB | 1234 | 80376.6797 |
| site B | AB | 12345 | 80376.6797 |
| site C | AA | 123 | 160753.359 |
| site C | AB | 1234 | 80376.6797 |
| site C | AB | 12345 | 80376.6797 |

When the past spend column is summed it totals 964520.15625

To break it down:

| site | subtier | part_number | past spend | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site A | AA | 123 | 160753.359 | 964520.15625 / 3 / 2 |
| site A | AB | 1234 | 80376.6797 | 964520.15625 / 3 / 2 / 2 |
| site A | AB | 12345 | 80376.6797 | 964520.15625 / 3 / 2 / 2 |

/ 3 / 2 / 2:

3 represents distinct count for site (Site A, B and C)
2 represents distinct count for subtier (AA, AB)
2 (last one) represents Site A --> AB has 2 part numbers

I need help building SQL for this.

I've tried:

```
   CASE
         WHEN (
             site_cnt != 0 AND subtier_cnt != 0 AND part_num_cnt
                 != 0 AND past_spend IS NOT NULL
        ) THEN ((past_spend/ site_cnt) / subtier__cnt)
             / part_num_cnt
        WHEN (
             site_cnt != 0 AND subtier_cnt = 0 AND part_num_cnt
                = 0 AND past_spend IS NOT NULL
        ) THEN (past_spend / site_cnt)
       ELSE past_spend
    END AS past_spend
```

This ends up being 53584.4531 for all rows which is incorrect

I've also tried dividing the past spend amount using a window function:

```
  past_spend / count() over (partition by site, subtier, part_number)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database supports `count(distinct)` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (964520.15625 /
        (count(distinct site) over () *
         count(distinct subtier) over (site) *
         count(distinct partnumber) over (partition by site, subtier)
        )
       )
from t;
```

There are ways to solve this (assuming the logic is correct) even in databases where `count(distinct)` is not supported as a window function.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff - this helped a lot. I'm using Presto which doesn't support Count(distinct) Over() but I was able to derive the distinct count otherwise and use the following:

          (964520.15625 / (site_cnt * subtier_cnt * count(partnumber) over (partition by 
           site, subtier)
             )
             )

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Heather . . . There is a relatively simple way to calculate the distinct count using window functions (not verbose, but pretty simple).